# flymake fails with "Wrong type argument: symbolp, (utf-8)"

Tags: emacs, flymake

I'm trying to get flymake to work, but when I run `flymake-mode`, I get the following error

```
switched OFF Flymake mode for buffer TdDisassemblerIde.cpp due to fatal status \
PROCERR, warning Failed to launch syntax check process 'make' with args (-s -C ./ \
CHK_SOURCES=TdDisassemblerIde_flymake.cpp SYNTAX_CHECK_MODE=1 check-syntax): Wrong type \    
argument: symbolp, (utf-8)
```

Any clues?

Comment: M-x toggle-debug-on-error then try again. You should get a stack that shows the incorrect parameter (which is a UTF-8 string but should be a symbol) and track back to what is set incorrectly. (Press q to quit the debugger.)

Comment: Nope, no stacktrace is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: the problem was that I had set `process-coding-system-alist` to contain the symbol `utf-8`, and apparently flymake does not like that. Setting `process-coding-system-alist` to `nil` solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When I have a problem with flymake, I do
`M-x set-variable flymake-log-level <RET> 3`

And then run flymake again (`M-x flymake-mode`).

Then look in the `*Messages*` buffer for a useful error message.

The last time this happened to me, about an hour ago, my check-syntax target in the flymakefile lacked a source module; I had added a module but had forgotten to add it to the list of files that should be included in a flymake compilation.  Modifying the makefile corrected it.  (This was for C#, but setting `flymake-log-level` should work to get a diagnosis for you too.)

Comment: Setting the loglevel did not show anything more than the error displayed above.